# Filemaker Import particular column

Tags: filemaker

I have created a table 'User' with two fields: 'username' and 'password'.

But I want to import only passwords from a csv file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When selecting a file to import, you have the ability to match which columns in the file should be imported and what they should match to. There's a column between the import file's fields on the left and the FileMaker fields on the right. If the column displays a right-pointing arrow, that field will be imported. If you click the right pointing arrow, it won't be imported. So match the password in the CSV to the password in FileMaker and make sure it has an arrow, but that there's no arrow next to the username field.

[image: Import Dialog]

If you're actually creating the database from the CSV file by opening it directly in FileMaker you can't control which fields are imported, but after they have been, you can remove the information imported for the username. Find all records in the Users table (Records>Show All Records, or Ctrl/Cmd-J) Click into the username field while in browse mode, delete any information there, and select Records>Replace Field Contents... (Ctrl/Cmd-=). Leave the option as `Replace with: ""`, and click "Replace". Be very careful with this feature, as it will set all the data for all of the records in the found set and there is no undo for it.

[image: Replace Dialog]